# using boost transform_iterator to std::transform conditionally

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

`_pimpl->_connections` is a `std::map` so its elements are `std::pair<KeyType, gcl::SectionConnectionT*>` I want to use a Predicate `gcl::SectionConnectionT::NotConnectedTo(r)` to filter out unnecessary values. but If I use

```
std::remove_copy_if(it_pair.first, it_pair.second, std::back_inserter(sectionConnections), gcl::SectionConnectionT::NotConnectedTo(r));
```

It tries to insert the `pair` into the vector. but the vector is of type `<gcl::SectionConnectionT*>` Some google search took me to [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html#id3) which I cannot understand how to understand. I used it like this. but getting compilations errorS

```
std::pair<CollectionT::iterator, CollectionT::iterator> it_pair = _pimpl->_connections.equal_range(l);
std::vector<gcl::SectionConnectionT*> sectionConnections;
std::remove_copy_if(it_pair.first, it_pair.second, boost::make_transform_iterator(std::back_inserter(sectionConnections), util::shorthand::pair_second()), gcl::SectionConnectionT::NotConnectedTo(r));
```

Comment: Boost.Iterators can be considered to be somewhat low-level, you may want to check Boost.Range instead. From the top of my head `remove_copy_if(it_pair | map_keys, std::back_inserter(sectionConnections), gcl::SectionConnectionT::NotConnectedTo(r))` would achieve what you want. Don't have the time to double-check and make an answer proper.

Answer (score 1):

The Boost.Iterator library is likely unable to deduce the return type of `until::shorthand::pair_second::operator()(CollectionT::value_type&) const`, so the returned `transform_iterator` is not modeling the Writable Lvalue Iterator concept, as is required to be used for the third parameter to `std::remove_copy_if` (the output iterator).

The following works, though:

```
//#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
//#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
//#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
//#include <boost/range/algorithm/remove_copy_if.hpp>

//namespace gcl {
//struct SectionConnectionT {
//    bool NotConnectedTo(RType r) const;
//    // ...
//};
//}

boost::remove_copy_if(it_pair | boost::adaptors::map_values,
    std::back_inserter(sectionConnections),
    boost::lambda::bind(&gcl::SectionConnectionT::NotConnectedTo, boost::lambda::_1, r));
```